# asp.net design not load on browser ( visual studio 2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project with master page and content page in content page design not load as their html,that is project solution version 5. I think this version code changed but  I'm trying to recover this from my solution version 4 since appear same problem i'm refreshing my browser but not work.........I don't understand what happened and what should i do now.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Product Info</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Invoice Number</h6>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxInvoice" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Name</h6>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="productNameDDL" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="" runat="server" OnTextChanged="productNameDDL_TextChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Quantity</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Quantity</h6>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalQuantity" CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="setPrice();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Price</h6>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalPrice" CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="setPrice();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Price/Item</h6>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPricePerItem" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>



    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Price</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sale Price/Item</h6>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxSalePricePerQuantity" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Comments</h6>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxComments" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[For better understand check this design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwgIa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you don't miss any reference to some CSS class. Try to remove CssClass="form-control" and see what happens.